# Ros2 navigation not working properly

Tags: ros, motion-planning, navigation, planning, nav2

I am trying Ackerman drive with nav2. The robot follows the path correctly but global planner doesn't update the path and then the robot stops.

[image: Rviz screenshot]

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you are trying to run. Which distro? Which launch file? Which config? Which behavior tree? Like this it is impossible to tell what is going on. Maybe also some logs are interesting. Did you check the global_path topic